# Non-integrable derivative of increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

Is there an example of an increasing and differentiable function $f$ on an interval $[a,b]$ such that its derivative is not Riemann integrable on the same interval?

Comment: Integrable in which sense?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Sorry, you are right to point it out: Riemann-Integrable

Comment: Consider the [Volterra's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function) and then add some linear function to make it increasing (which is possible since the Volterra function has a bounded derivative).